# Laravel Vapor - Assets (logo) on maintenance mode page

Tags: laravel, amazon-cloudfront, laravel-vapor

[According to the docs](https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/projects/environments.html#maintenance-mode) we are able to put a `503.html` document inside the root of our Laravel project.

> **You may customize the maintenance mode splash screen for your application by placing a 503.html file in your application's root directory.**

I would however love to be able to put one or more assets on this page (for example our Logo) to make this page better more personal. Laravel Vapor automatically uploads your static assets to cloudfront, [which is not a problem if you're using the `asset()` helper](https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/projects/deployments.html#assets). However, are there any solutions already being made? I can't find any.

Is there anyone who has created a solution to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

With Vapor every time you deploy all the assets get a new cloudfront url. This is mostly fine for js and css which we change often. Images, logos etc do not change much.

Better to make another bucket on aws and hard code the path the image file in your 503. Doesn't need to be deployed every time. Your users browsers can cache it for as long as you set it in the bucket.

I'd like Vapor to only change asset urls if the files have changed but so far that is not the case.